# Is there a way to get `updated_by` field when handling a webhook? (Strapi)

Tags: javascript, strapi

**Problem:** I'm creating a activity log thing in Strapi using webhooks. When dealing with collections I created I know there's this model option you set to get who created and updated the collection. However I also needed to extend this to Media Library and as far as I'm concerned that should be possible because Strapi tables for ML already have the attributes create_by and updated_by.

**My toughts:** So I came up with a knex custom select that you can see down below:

```
await knex('upload_file').where('id', media.id).select();
```

It works just fine. However this would call the database twice and this is a concern as I work in a really big company and that might raise costs a lot.

**Final Question:** So is there a solution to that? Maybe the same approach as collections I created? Or even allow this option globally so every model on strapi would return this two fields. (I might extend this for all collections I have in the future).

Comment: I guess changing `populateCreatorFields` globally would solve the problem. But how?!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to an answer just go for middleware, it's easier and more reliable.

Follow [this](https://medium.com/@adenleabbey/audit-log-trail-with-strapi-74f6bdf70daf) tutorial and you should be good.